Date time format in Swiftexcel
I have the date as follows: "07-05-2024 07:41:57". I want to write in the xlsx file using swiftexcel. I am using the following style for date only
var style = new Style
{
    NumberFormat = NumberFormat.Custom("dd/mmm/yyyy hh:mm:ss")
};

can someone please help on the style format to be used

That looks correct, what's your problem?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Your thinking is correct. This will also require using the .Pro version of SwiftExcel. Don't forget to convert your date to OADate and you should be good.
Here is a full working example:
var style = new Style
{
    NumberFormat = NumberFormat.Custom("dd/mmm/yyyy hh:mm:ss")
};

var dateToExport = new DateTime(2024, 05, 07, 7, 41, 57);
using (var ew = new ExcelWriter("C:\\temp\\test.xlsx", style))
{
    ew.Write($"{dateToExport.ToOADate()}", 1, 2, 1, 1, DataType.Number);
}

